# Sum up multiple controllers in one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller (`sampleCtrl.js`) which is basically three controllers in one. (`sampleCtrl`, `sampleEditCtrl` and `sampleCreateCtrl`).

What I want to do is seperate these three controllers in standalone-files (like `sampleCtrl.js`, `sampleEditCtrl.js` and so on) and one (controller) file which I include in my index.html that sums these three controllers up.

Is this even possible? I can't find anything appropriate on the internet, maybe I search for the wrong term.

EDIT:

Content of `sampleCtrl.js`

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data) {
    //some code
});

app.controller('sampleEditCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data) {
    //some code
});

app.controller('sampleCreateCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data) {
    //some code
});
```

Each controller within that file is really big so I want to seperate these three controllers in a file each (eg.: `sampleEditCtrl` -> `sampleEditCtrl.js`), so each controller has its own file.

I don't want to include all three controller files in my `index.html`.

I'm looking for some sort of suming these three controllers up, so I only have to include one file instead of three.

So instead of

```
<script src="app/controller/sampleCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/sampleEditCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/sampleCreateCtrl.js"></script>
```

i just want to include one file for all three like so

```
<script src="app/controller/sampleCtrlWrappedUp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Too broad unfortunately, however - Read about [$ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/)

Comment: Are you trying to simply package all your scripts into one file as part of a build/minification process?

Comment: If I understand your question then you want it as nested tag or use as parallel? it may possible with parallel and nested in both way

Comment: @AlonEitan I took a look at it and it seems to meet my use-case, thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what 'sum up' is supposed to mean. The code that illustrates the case could help.

Comment: You should wrap with directive

Comment: I guess this means 'in one file' and not 'in one controller' then. This is what modules and bundling tools (Webpack, Rollup, Browserify) are for. Libs like RequireJS and SystemJS allow to do this in less efficient way but without bundling step.